# Remove string from the link href

Tags: php, jquery-pagination

I'm using a jQuery pagination script and I'm using the onChange function so if a user click on the page number it does redirect him to the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` + it adds an page number to the request url, but if I will click on some pages several times then the request url looks like this: `&page=3&page=1&page=10` ... etc.

The code looks like this:

```
onChange : function(page){
    window.location = '" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "&page='+page;
}
```

Now I need to remove `$page=???` from the url if it already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = preg_replace_all("/\\&page=[^\\&]+/", "", $url);
```

`$url` will contain the url barring the page attribute

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that every time the user clicks on your link, the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is the current URL and you are just appending an extra string to the end.

You need to set the get variable to the page you want then just change this variable when your function is called. Something like:

```
$_GET["page"] = page;
```